# Microsoft not disposing of their own objects?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, dispose

**EDIT:** Server is MOSS 2007 Enterprise, running SP1 and all patches up to, but not including, SP2.  SP2 is coming soon.

---

In one of my SharePoint apps, I am getting this warning & stacktrace over and over (with different GUIDS): since it's only one of my apps, I assume there's something in my project's code, but SPDisposeCheck returns clean, and there's nothing in the logs that point to my code.

Any ideas on how I can track this down?

**Error I'm getting:**

> Potentially excessive number of
>   SPRequest objects (9) currently
>   unreleased on thread 1. Ensure that
>   this object or its parent (such as an
>   SPWeb or SPSite) is being properly
>   disposed. Allocation Id for this
>   object:
>   {1DFFC1ED-E69E-4580-8D7B-45EDB5C49188}

Stack trace of current allocation:

```
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.Add(SPRequest request, Boolean shareable)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureSPRequest()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Request()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetFileOrFolderProperties(String strUrl, ListDocsFlags listDocsFlags, Boolean throwException)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.PropertiesCore(Boolean throwException)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_Properties()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_Level()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleXmlUtilities.configFile(String myUniqueId, SPFileLevel level)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleXmlUtilities.ConfigurationXml(String configProvider, Boolean isBuiltInConfigFile)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleXmlUtilities.GetConsoleNodeCollection(String configXml, ConsoleNode prePopulatedRootNode)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleXmlUtilities.GetConsoleNodeCollection(String configXml)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleXmlUtilities.GetConsoleNodeCollectionFromXmlFile(String configName, Boolean isBuiltInConfigFile)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.XmlConsoleDataSource.LoadTreeFromConfigXml()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.XmlConsoleDataSource.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.ForceInitLoad(EventArgs e)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.PublishingSiteActionsMenuCustomizer.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)
```

Comment: What Service Pack Level is your MOSS installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently [expected behavior](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/potentially-excessive-number-of-sprequest-objects-coming-from-microsofts-own-c).